# issue in my algorithm when the 'ACE' card appears in the hand of my blackjack game

Tags: java, algorithm, oop

i'm trying to write a blackJack game using Java and i'm facing this algorithm issue, the `Hand class` will choose randomly 3 card from `Card class` if the `ACE` card appears in the hand it will takes a value of 1 or 11, this is the wished result :

```
Welcome to the BlackJack table. Let's play !
Your hand is currently : [A, 8, A] : [10, 20, 20, 30]
The best score is: 20
Welcome to the BlackJack table. Let's play !
Your hand is currently : [K, J, 4] : [24]
```

this is the method i writhe to do this :

```
public List<Integer> count() {
        LinkedList<Integer> List = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        LinkedList<Integer> List2 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        List.add(0);
        if(this.cardList.size()>0) {
            for (Card c : cardList) {
                for (int i = 0; i < List.size(); i++) {
                    int val = List.get(i);
                        List2.add(List.set(i, c.getPoints() + val  ));
                    if(c.getPoints() == 1) {
                        List2.add(List.getFirst() + (val + 11));

                    }
                }
            }

        }

        return List2;
    }
```

and this is what i get :

```
Welcome to the BlackJack table. Let's play !
Your Hand is currently : [5(♥), 8(♦), 8(♥)] [0, 5, 13]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this seems kind of like homework, i'm going to try to help you with one way to solve your problem.

```
 Separate the Aces since they have a variable value ( 1 / 11 )
 Calculate the value of the other cards.
 if you have Aces{  
      Do all the combinations of the values of the Aces.     
      //( Example with 2 aces: 1+1 ; 11+1; 11+11; 1+11).   
      for each combination sum it to the other cards and add it to the list.   
 }else{         
       add just the other cards value
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a simpler approach is to count the lowest possible score (if aces score 1), and (separately) whether you have an ace or not. (So you now know whether you can add 10 to the score or not.)

A player will never add 20 to their score if they have 2 aces, as that will result in a score of at least 22 (which is bad for the player).

Then at the end of the counting phase construct an array with the first element being the lowest score. If you have an ace present, add a second element with the lowest score + 10.